# Loading Google Maps within an jQuery UI accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have integrated Google Maps fine but when I try to display this within an accordion I cannot see this displayed on the screen even though I can see the google map object within the DOM. I am trying to trigger the google.maps event to resize the map but with no joy - can anybody assist?

// js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// initialise gmaps with default data
map = new GMaps({
    div: '#gmapsjsMmap',
    lat: 52.4801,
    lng: -1.8835,
    zoom: 7
});

$("#registration_form_area")
    .accordion({
        change: function(event, ui)
        {
            google.maps.event.trigger($('#gmapsjsMmap',ui.newContent)
                .data('map'), 'resize');
        }
    });

}); // end doc ready
```

// html code

```
 <div id="registration_form_area" class="hidden">
  <div id="gmapsjsMmap"></div>
  <!-- more code -->
```

I am using this google maps js library from here - 
https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Comment: what is class "hidden"? I am not sure what the problem is? seems to be working https://jsfiddle.net/gd59j6y3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting height and width to the map's element and change the function as shown:
**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // initialise gmaps with default data
    map = new GMaps({
        div: '#gmapsjsMmap',
        lat: 52.4801,
        lng: -1.8835,
        zoom: 7
    });
    $("#registration_form_area")
        .accordion({
            activate: function(event, ui) {
                google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            }
        });

});
```

**CSS:**

```
#gmapsjsMmap {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="registration_form_area">
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum
            a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div>

        <div id="gmapsjsMmap"></div>
        <p>
            Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In suscipit faucibus urna.
        </p>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 3</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam
            nisi, eu iaculis leo purus venenatis dui.
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Section 4</h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean lacinia mauris vel est.
        </p>
        <p>
            Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/R9nyW/233/